# Javascript to insert small set of characters from previous, next file name in the same location

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, return-value, filenames, batch-processing

I am looking for two sets of coding. One to return the first 4 or 5 letters of the previous file in the same folder, and one to return the first 4 or 5 characters in the next filename in the same folder. The requested number of characters changes, I don't know if there is a way to return all the characters in the front of the filename until an underscore("_') is reached in the filename.  For example, I might have "LS100_Photo" for a filename, and the next document might by "T220_File". I am only interested in returning the first section of the filename up until the underscore.  The overall goal I am trying to use this to batch-process and insert a set of hyperlinks to jump to the first page of the previous file, or the first page of the next file in the folder on a specified location on the PDF page, and to be able to do this on multiple PDF documents at a time.

The two different results that would work for me.

1. This code inputs as a text string on the PDF within an inch of each other, "Start of Previous filename" and next to it "Start of Next Filename".
2. The other result that would work would be this code actually puts a relative hyperlink on the PDF with each one within an inch of each other. one that goes to the previous file, and one that goes to the next file.

Comment: Are you able to provide what you've tried that is not working? I don't see a specific programming issue here.

Comment: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it." https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic